# When to alert that I won't be extending the contract?

Tags: professionalism, job-change, notice-period

I work now under a 3 month contract which is on the fairly beginning (Research position) and they offered me the prospect of extending the contract (like 3 more months). However, I have found a good job for a permanent position and they told me to start right away when my current 3 month contract ends, which I aim to do. My plan is to say to the current employer about the situation, however, we are on the fairly beginning and in my opinion it will sound bit disappointing since we have not achieved anything yet.

When should I inform my employer about my plans?

Comment: So you plan on taking the perm position?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am considering.

Comment: @Lilienthal I took your commentary into regard and updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your contract give any terms for renewal/non-renewal etc?

I would suggest giving them a month or so (if there is that long left in the 3 month contract) notice. I don't think there is any need to give actual notice like a permanent role as you are on a fixed term contract. But it would be curteous to do so to allow them to start looking for a replacement. Maybe bring it up next time they mention the extension.

I would ignore if it sounds dissapointing etc. You have to look after yourself and a permanent position clearly offers much more security and opportunity for progression. Ensure there is a good handover of any research you have done and keep relations good with the research company.

Comment: No there is no sign in the contract in terms of renewal. I firmly agree with you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that to to be fair to your employer you should tell them **as soon as you are certain that you are not going to be renewing**. This allows them to prepare best for your leaving, and has no downside to you.

However, is 'having a good permanent job offer' the same as being certain you will take it? It may be better than the renewal you think you will get, but there is al least a possibility that your current employer likes you enough to make you a permanent offer and to better the offer you have. That's another good reason to tell them about this offer early, and give them a chance to negotiate to keep you. Unless of course there is no offer that would make you stay. Even if you think its unlikely that an offer could make you stay, giving them the chance to make one is likely to improve relations, not damage them.

Comment: "*there is al least a possibility that your current employer likes you enough to make you permanent offer*" Good point. If that's something the OP would want to consider that conversation should even be along the lines of "*Since I want to move to full-time work I wouldn't be able to consider a temporary renewal*". His current employer may not think to evaluate that as an option without that push.